# Libgdx draw a sprite in top of an isometric tile

Tags: libgdx, isometric

I have this isometric map and im using `IsometricTiledMapRenderer` to render the map I have a `OrthographicCamera`. I know where each tile is in the isometric map, but the isometric map is kinda rotated?

So I was wondering how to convert Map Coordinates to Isometric and viceversa?

Here I tried to draw a color cube in each tile coordinates....
[image]

---

Thanks in advance, I have been struggling with this for 2 days, and my lack english vocabulary isnt helping with the research, please some one point me to something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the Isometric renderer I found this piece of code (slightly edited):

```
private void init () {

    // create the isometric transform
    isoTransform = new Matrix4();

    isoTransform.idt();


    // isoTransform.translate(0, 32, 0);

    isoTransform.scale((float)(Math.sqrt(2.0) / 2.0), (float)(Math.sqrt(2.0) / 4.0), 1.0f);

    isoTransform.rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -45);


    // ... and the inverse matrix
    isoTransform.inv();

}


private Vector3 translateScreenToIso (Vector2 vec) {

    Vector3 screenPos = new Vector3(vec.x, vec.y, 0);

    screenPos.mul(isoTransform);


    return screenPos;

}
```

Try using this to convert your screen coordinates to Isometric coordinates.

Comment: I tried this Yesterday with no luck :/ thanks for your reply!

Comment: Actually I tried this again and it just worked, thanks man really thanks alot